# SQL Server condition case doesnt work as intended

Tags: sql-server

I want my SQL to display the overdue count when the condition is the status name showed closed on the exact due date then the count will be set as 1. For example, on the due date, the status name only became closed.

```
select 
    category, COUNT(overdue) as overdue2 
from 
    (select 
         Category, due,
         case when DATEDIFF(day, Due, SYSDATETIME()) = 0 then 1   
              else 0 
         end as overdue 
     from 
         FeedbackDetail 
     where 
         StatusName = 'Closed' and  
         FeedbackDatetime >= '2018-01-01') a 
Group by 
    Category
```

My expected result is to display the count where the statusname is closed on the exact due date time.

Any idea on this?

Comment: where is the `condition case` statement ? Please post the query

Comment: select category,COUNT(overdue) as overdue2 from ( Select  Category,due,Case when DATEDIFF(day,Due,SYSDATETIME())=0 then 1 else 0 end as overdue From FeedbackDetail Where StatusName='Closed' and FeedbackDatetime>='2018-01-01' ) a Group by Category) a14 on a1.Category=a14.Category

Comment: please update the original post with the query. Also please show sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1):

The COUNT aggregate function counts existant (non-null) values, so it will count 0 as well as 1. Since you did not post the whole query and we have no idea what `a1` is, the only solution that can be proposed is:

Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the query like given below for better performance and working.

```
DECLARE @currentDateTime DATETIME = GETDATE()
select 
    category, SUM(overdue) as overdue2 
from 
    (select 
         Category, 
         case when DATEDIFF(day, Due, @currentDateTime) = 0 then 1   
              else 0 
         end as overdue 
     from 
         FeedbackDetail 
     where 
         StatusName = 'Closed' and  
         FeedbackDatetime >= '2018-01-01') a 
Group by 
    Category
```